# LTC7813 buck-boost IC max output power

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, buck-boost

I am developing a power supply for a 24V 10A BLDC motor, which has to work with car and truck batteries (12V-24V). The real thing is that those batteries never have 12V nor 24V, instead, they could be above or below their respective value, so I am in the need of a SMPS.

I started looking for Flyback topology but after that I found that they aren't suitable for this amount of power. That's how I arrived to the buck-boost topology.

I found LTC7813 buck-boost IC which I liked pretty much, but reading the datasheet [(link here)](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/7813f.pdf), I cant find a parameter that leads to know how much output power it can handle. I know it is primarily limitated by the MOSFETs, inductances and discrete semiconductors, but I need to ensure that the LTC7813 can handle around 350W (240W + 110W for margin, because there can be load surges, for example in motor startup). Maybe someone with more experience than me can help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LTC7813 has external switches so the amount of power is determined by the inductor, mosfets, the sense resistor and parasitic values of these components. Use LT power cad to determine how much power the LTC7813 can handle with external components. You may be able to parallel the switching mosfets to get lower switching resistances and lower power dissipation per part.

If you search for 24V output with 15A the LTC7813 comes up on the list in LTpowercad

Comment: I didn't know that tool! Thank you for the help

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment